# Yet another simple Rock, Paper and Scissors game

Tags: rust, rock-paper-scissors

I implemented [a simple CLI based rock-paper-scissors game](https://github.com/conqp/rps) in Rust.
The player plays against the computer.
Each game has three rounds, not counting draws.

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "rps"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
```

`lib.rs`

```rust
use rand::{
    distributions::{Distribution, Standard},
    Rng,
};
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter};
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum RPS {
    Rock,
    Paper,
    Scissors,
}

impl Display for RPS {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}",
            match self {
                Self::Rock => '',
                Self::Paper => '',
                Self::Scissors => '✀',
            }
        )
    }
}

impl PartialOrd<Self> for RPS {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        match (self, other) {
            (Self::Rock, Self::Paper) => Some(Ordering::Less),
            (Self::Rock, Self::Scissors) => Some(Ordering::Greater),
            (Self::Paper, Self::Rock) => Some(Ordering::Greater),
            (Self::Paper, Self::Scissors) => Some(Ordering::Less),
            (Self::Scissors, Self::Rock) => Some(Ordering::Less),
            (Self::Scissors, Self::Paper) => Some(Ordering::Greater),
            (_, _) => None,
        }
    }
}

impl Ord for RPS {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        match self.partial_cmp(other) {
            Some(order) => order,
            None => Ordering::Equal,
        }
    }
}

impl Distribution<RPS> for Standard {
    fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> RPS {
        match rng.gen_range(0..=2) {
            0 => RPS::Rock,
            1 => RPS::Paper,
            _ => RPS::Scissors,
        }
    }
}

impl FromStr for RPS {
    type Err = &'static str;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s.trim().to_lowercase().as_str() {
            "r" => Ok(Self::Rock),
            "p" => Ok(Self::Paper),
            "s" => Ok(Self::Scissors),
            _ => Err("invalid string"),
        }
    }
}
```

`main.rs`

```
use rand::random;
use rps::RPS;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let mut rounds: u8 = 0;
    let mut score: i8 = 0;

    loop {
        if rounds >= 3 {
            break;
        }

        let computer: RPS = random();
        let user = read_user();

        match user.cmp(&computer) {
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("Draw: {} = {}", user, computer);
                continue;
            }
            Ordering::Less => {
                println!("You lost: {} < {}", user, computer);
                score -= 1;
            }
            Ordering::Greater => {
                println!("You won: {} > {}", user, computer);
                score += 1;
            }
        }

        rounds += 1;
    }

    match score.cmp(&0) {
        Ordering::Equal => println!("The game ended in a draw."),
        Ordering::Less => println!("The computer won the game."),
        Ordering::Greater => println!("The player won the game."),
    }
}

fn read_user() -> RPS {
    loop {
        print!("Your selection (r/p/s): ");
        stdout().flush().expect("Could not flush STDOUT.");
        let mut buf = String::new();

        if stdin().read_line(&mut buf).is_ok() {
            match RPS::from_str(&buf) {
                Ok(rps) => return rps,
                Err(error) => println!("{}: {}", error, buf),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to have feedback on the general code style and especially the use of trait implementations in `lib.rs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `PartialOrd` and `None`

You're not supposed to return `None` in `partial_cmp()` when `a` and `b` are equal. You're supposed to return `Some(Ordering::Equal)`. Only weird types that have no total ordering return `None`, such as `NaN` and `Nan` in floats, where it is neither `==` nor `!=`.

If you do have total ordering, it is better to implement the logic in `Ord` to make sure you never return `None`, and then implement `PartialOrd` in terms of it: `Some(self.cmp(other))`.

### `PartialOrd<Self>`

The `<Self>` is redundant. `Self` is the default.

#### `Stdout` and `Stdin`

I wouldn't do this in this program since the I/O is definitely not a performance problem, but if you're doing a lot of I/O know that you can lock stdin and stdout for faster access to them (but this means you cannot access them without the lock), and you can also wrap them with buffering to make them even faster:

```rust
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, Write};

fn read_user() -> RPS {
    let mut stdout = BufWriter::new(stdout().lock());
    let mut stdin = BufReader::new(stdin().lock());
    loop {
        write!(stdout, "Your selection (r/p/s): ").unwrap();
        stdout.flush().expect("Could not flush STDOUT.");
        let mut buf = String::new();

        if stdin.read_line(&mut buf).is_ok() {
            match RPS::from_str(&buf) {
                Ok(rps) => return rps,
                Err(error) => println!("{}: {}", error, buf),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Using `ThreadRng` explicitly

Again, this doesn't matter in this example because the code is not performance sensitive, but it is faster to store the [`ThreadRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html) in a variable instead of calling `random()` if you do it many times:

```rust
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rounds: u8 = 0;
    let mut score: i8 = 0;

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    
    loop {
        if rounds >= 3 {
            break;
        }

        let computer: RPS = rng.gen();
    // ...
}
```

#### `use std::fmt::Debug` is redundant.

Because `Debug` is already in the prelude. Not the trait - the derive macro. The compiler doesn't warn about that unfortunately ([but see clippy#1124](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/1124)).

#### Don't use `Ord` or `PartialOrd`

[By the contract of `PartialOrd` (and `Ord`), it should be transitive (`a < b` and `b < c` means `a < c`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html). Your implementation *does not* fulfill that criteria (e.g. `Rock < Paper` and `Paper < Scissors` but `Rock > Scissors`), therefore you cannot implement `PartialOrd`.

Use your own method to compare `RPS` and checks who win. I recommend also using your own enum for the result (and not `Ordering`), because for me at least, `Ordering::Greater` for example does not clearly mean left wins right.